# Multiple VDI images for VM to one?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a VM which has 4 VDI images 20-35 GB's and i am wondering if there is any way these all can be merged into a bigger single VDI ( lets say 200 GB? )

Virtualbox version is 6.0

Comment: Need more details: 1) What's the host/guest OS? 2) How are the VDIs mounted on the guest (filesystem/mount point)? There is no Virtualbox command that will merge separate VDIs; snapshots, yes, but not like what you're describing.

Comment: Host is KDE Neon, guest is centos 7. The mount points are different for /var and root.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: before doing anything, make a backup of your VM!

I think the easiest way to accomplish this is to expand the 1st VDI (the one with /) to the size you want (*see the VBoxManage modifymedium command here:* https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#vboxmanage-modifyvdi), copy the data over, then reconfigure your /etc/fstab to reflect the changes. Once you know that everything works, remove the unused VDIs.

Comment: Will try and share how it went

Comment: I was able to to `pvmove` the volume(s) into a new disk, eventually had to rebuild the VM with a different structure due to other needs. Thanks for the comments on the question.